To find the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ f^{(n-1)}(x)}{f^{(n)}(x)} $

Given $ f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function satisfying the functional equation
$f(x+y)=3^x f(y) + 3^y f(x) , \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
Then find
$\Omega =\lim_ {n\rightarrow \infty} \sum _{k=1}^{n}  \frac{ f^{(k-1)}(x)}{f^{(k)}(x)} $
($f^{(n)}(x) $ is the $n-th$ derivative of $f(x)$)
My attempt :-
Given $f(x+y)=3^x f(y) + 3^y f(x) , \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ .
Dividing both sides by $3^{x+y}$, we get
$\frac{ f(x+y)}{3^{x+y}} =\frac {f(x)}{3^x} +\frac {f(y)}{3^y} $
Let $g(x)=\frac {f(x)}{3^x}$  Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y), \forall x,y$
Thus $g(x)=kx , k=g(1)$
So $g^{(n)}(x) = 0 , \forall n \ge 2, $ , the $n-th$ derivative
So $f(x) = 3^x g(x) $ Differentiating both sides $n$ times using Leibnitz Theorem ,
$f^{(n)}(x)= 3^x (\ln 3)^n g(x)+ n3^x (\ln 3)^{n-1} g'(x)  $
$= k(\ln 3)^{n-1} 3^x(x\ln 3 +n) $
So $\frac{ f^{(n-1)}(x)}{f^{(n)}(x)} = \frac 1{\ln 3}\frac {x\ln 3+n-1}{x\ln 3+n}   
  \rightarrow  \frac 1{\ln 3}\neq 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
Thus the series must diverge and $\Omega$ doesn't exist
Is there any mistake here as the question ask to find it instead of checking existence ?

I don't see any mistake. I think the question is wrong.
